# R-E-S-P-E-C-T earned too early

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, daily-reputation-limit, winter-bash-2013

The R-E-S-P-E-C-T hat is documented as "hit the daily reputation cap", but I got it on Math.SE at only 225 rep points today, of which 45 came from accepts. There are still 20 points to go before I cap.

Perhaps the description should have been "earn 200 reputation point in a day", like how the Epic/Legendary badges work?

Comment: Rep cap is 200. You say you have 225? Hmmmmm

Comment: @Oded: Rep cap is 200 but _does not apply_ to points from accepts and bonuses.

Comment: It's never too early to earn r-e-s-p-e-c-t, but it can sometimes be too late. We're just being cautious is all.

Comment: Looks correct to me. In the 1 day timespan he has +18 votes and +3 checkmarks (being the math guru we should just assume he added this correctly the first time :P).

Comment: @Travis: The rep cap only kicks in after 20 (answer) upvotes. At +18 there are still two to go.

Comment: @HenningMakholm - That would be the "looks correct" part about this bug report :). He is 2 votes short of the cap for the day yet still earned R-E-S-P-E-C-T.

Comment: @TravisJ: Oh, sorry then. Thought you said that the _behavior_ looks correct.

Comment: Since the "rep cap" badges (Mortarboard, Epic, Legendary) use 200 as a target and not actually hitting the rep cap, I'm going to guess this is status by design.

Comment: I earned this hat from being awarded a 250-point bounty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The daily reputation cap is 200 reputation. While accepts are not part of the reputation cap itself, it is demonstrable that "hitting the reputation cap" is intended to mean "get at least 200 reputation", which is the same way the mortarboard badge, epic badge and legendary badge function.

In these instances, there are only a small number of things that do not count towards the reputation cap (including association bonus) so it's reasonable to accept that "getting 200 reputation" is the intended target for this hat.