# I don't get no R-E-S-P-E-C-T

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2013

[image: no respect]

After slaving away on meta, I finally hit the rep cap yesterday. By "slaving away", I mostly mean making an [off-hand joke about star colors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211877/212780), but whatever. I got my first meta Mortarboard, and was expecting a shiny(?) black ribbon to go along with it. I think it would look rather dashing pinned to my fedora. Even if it doesn't, it would add to my hat-count, which is sorely lacking.

So I waited. As I know, it's *always* a caching issue. But alas, after a couple hours passed with no sign of a ribbon, I grew despondent.

So I waited. After all, many things around here happen at the end of the UTC day. I know, I know, apparently [R-E-S-P-E-C-T isn't one of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212230/which-hats-are-awarded-at-the-end-of-the-utc-day#comment682931_212230), but I had to find out for myself. Of course, you can guess how this turned out for me.

My next thought was to search for others with the same problem. The only post I found was someone reporting [they got it too early](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211900/212780), which is obviously not the same issue.

Then, I thought maybe it just isn't awarded *on meta sites*. After a [cursory examination](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/meta.stackoverflow.com), I ruled this out as well. MSO being special and all, it appears that several users have earned it here.

Seriously, how do I get this thing? It's not a secret hat, and the description is brutally straightforward.

Comment: You don't want to hear that I just now earned this one on Meta as well, right?

Comment: Not particularly :(

Comment: That's not the only weird thing: your profile now shows you as having earned 201 rep yesterday ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FEaBi.png)), made up of a bunch of upvotes and one edit for +2. I don't see how that could possibly add up to 201; depending on how exactly the cap is calculated, I could believe either 200 or 202, but 201 just seems so... _odd_. ;)

Comment: I still see 200. +2 for an edit, -1 for a DV, and 20 upvotes. My last upvote only gave 9, so it seems right to me.

Comment: We see 201 because we don't see the -1 so the numbers must match. I don't think there's a doubt you hit rep cap. Did you get other hats?

Comment: maybe a [recalc](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've gotten three other hats since then, if that's what you're asking. In all, 15 distinct ones, 19 counting dupes.

Comment: We need to confirm if this is a bug. Quick - vote some of my post so that I can replicate the problem when I reach the cap ^_^.

Comment: Seems we're "finding out what it means to you" ...*sigh*

Comment: Maybe, just maybe... it's insane but... you have -50 yesterday on Stack Overflow, so maybe it was reduced from your Meta rep in the hat calculation?

Comment: @ShadowWizard That would be horrible. Denying my hat for placing a bounty would make me very sad. I assumed bounty rep was totally separate from cap rep(especially on a site with completely separate rep), but who knows?

Comment: @GenericHolidayName I know, it's a really wild guess but who knows... we've seen weirder bugs!

Comment: If it was a bounty on meta I could see it, because it does seem to be given when you've earned 200 rep in a day, not when you actually rep cap (as others have gotten the badge when they hit 200 rep in a day without rep capping) but you *did* hit +200 rep on meta that day, so that shouldn't be the issue.  I'm reasonably sure it's not a +200 rep throughout the network; if it is, that'd be...weird.

Comment: It is not 200 rep throughout the network. First, which profile would host the hat? Second, I have had 200 across the network and not received this hat.

Comment: *sock it to me, sock it to me, sock it to me....*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The criteria for R-E-S-P-E-C-T are now identical to those for the Mortarboard badge. While that's not *precisely* the rep cap, it's at least a strict superset; in other words, *if* you hit the rep cap, *then* you get the hat. We could change the hat's description to match the badge<sup>1</sup>, but I like the fact that this hat might teach a few users about the existence of the rep cap.

So, with all due R-E-S-P-E-C-T, you just received a new hat.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>The same thing happened for the badge itself at some point. It's close to impossible to query for precisely all the users that have ever hit the rep cap in performant way, so while both the badge and the hat are inspired by the rep cap, they don't match it 100%.</sub>

Comment: I don't understand why he didn't get the hat though? In what way he didn't hit rep cap two days ago?

Comment: @ShadowWizard He did hit the rep cap. The criteria before the fix were not a superset of the repcap criteria. You could hit the cap without getting the hat, which was obviously broken.

Comment: This was a great post to see first thing in the morning. Thanks!

Comment: R-E-S-P-E-C-T Hi5 @GHN. I got it too! :)