# Hit rep cap, but didn't get the R-E-S-P-E-C-T hat

Tags: support, reputation, winter-bash-2013

I hit the reputation cap in S.O. Actually by more, I had 194 rep when the last upvote gave me 6 points (to be 200). I got the bronze badge, but didn't get the R-E-S-P-E-C-T hat.

I got most of the points that day by edits. Is that the reason?

Comment: Me too, but no response yet: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212384/212780

Comment: oh, too bad :( surely someone must know

Comment: I've noticed that hats don't get awarded immediately.  I've had hats awarded upwards of 4 minutes after fulfilling requirements

Comment: I know, but mine was hours ago, yesterday actually @damienc88